# Change the pixel from which an element is positioned

Tags: javascript, html, css

By default in JavaScript elements are positioned according to their top left most pixel. Is there any way I can change which pixel the element is positioned by? I'd like to position an element according to its bottom left corner instead of its top left corner. I've done a bit of Google searching and can't find any questions like this, though its completely possible that I'm just not searching the right keywords.

Comment: You can accommodate for the width and or height defining the bottom and or right being the right  = left + width or bottom = top + height. Youc an also simply target the bottom or right of an element positioned with absolute

Answer (score 1):

As with all things, there are numerous viable approaches. You can set the parent with:

```
position: relative;
```

And assign the child element:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Another way to achieve this without having to resort to the "position: absolute;" property is assigning the parent element:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
```

Of course this will all depend with your markup. The examples provided are assuming you have a simple hierarchy of a parent div and a child div.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm asking. I'm asking for a way for ```position: absolute``` to position an element based off of the bottom left corner rather than the top left corner.

Comment: Well perhaps you can edit the question to specify that you wanted to pull it off with a "position: absolute".  And the first proposed solution will always grant that the children of the parent start at the bottom left of their container. I don't understand why you don't consider it a feasible solution.